# create TypeModel at runtime using Protobuf-Net, Unexpected sub-type

Tags: serialization, protobuf-net

I have the class structure below and would like to serialize it at runtime using `Protobuf-Net`. Unfortunately I get error "Unexpected sub-type: Web2Pdf". Why?

```
var web2PdfEntity = new Web2Pdf();
web2PdfEntity.Property1 = 1; 
web2PdfEntity.Property2 = 2;
    web2PdfEntity.Property3 = 3;

var model = TypeModel.Create();
model.Add(typeof (EntityBase), true).AddSubType(20000, typeof (WebEntity)).AddSubType(30000,typeof (Web2Pdf));                
model.CompileInPlace();



  using (var stream = new FileStream(@"C:\1.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
{
   model.Serialize(stream, web2PdfEntity); //Get exception here!
}


[ProtoContract]
public abstract class EntityBase
{
   [ProtoMember(1011)]
   public int Property1 { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
public abstract class WebEntity : EntityBase
{
   [ProtoMember(1012)]
   public int Property2 { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
public sealed class Web2Pdf : WebEntity
{
   [ProtoMember(1013)]
   public int Property3 { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subtypes must be associated with the *immediate* parent, so: `EntityBase` needs to know about `WebEntity`, and `WebEntity` needs to know about `Web2Pdf` (rather than `EntityBase` knowing about both and `WebEntity` not knowing about `Web2Pdf`).

For info, smaller tag numbers are more efficient, too - but up to you.

Additionally, this can all be done via `[ProtoInclude(...)]`, which can be more convenient if the sub-type numbers are fixed.

Comment: To further elaborate on what Marc said... AddSubType() returns the same MetaType it was called on, so you could chain AddSubType() calls to the same type... You want to do a model[typeof(WebEntity)].AddSubType(30000, typeof(Web2Pdf)); to set everything straight...

Comment: Indeed, it's *immediate* which is vitally important, you can't protoinclude the whole class tree on the root